# Python script to extract reports from Qlik view

Tags: python-3.x, series, qlikview

I have a python script which should assist to download a series of reports from Qlik view. The ID's of these reports are listed in a separate excel workbook, on my PC, which has several columns helping the script to pick the needed reports to be downloaded and uploaded on my machine.

I get this error: "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'is_monotonic'"

the full message looks like this:

Loading QlikView objects list from V:\Sales\Dealers...\Targets_split_per channel\qv_extract_config.xlsx
Number of QlikView objects to extract: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users...\Desktop\test.py", line 18, in 
print('Sorted by Application:',qv_extract_config.Application.is_monotonic)
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6204, in **getattr**
return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'is_monotonic'

i am expecting to have a series of reports to be extracted from qlikview on my PC

Comment: where is the code ? the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)